# what ports are required for copying file from one windows server to other

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

what ports are required for copying file from one windows server to other.
This is required to raise a firewall request in our environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
137 -> udp
138 -> udp
139 -> tcp
445 -> udp & tcp
```

source:- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/298804/internet-firewalls-can-prevent-browsing-and-file-sharing